# Reference request for the following theorem in Von Neumann algebras.

Tags: reference-request, operator-theory, operator-algebras, adjoint-operators, von-neumann-algebras

I know the following result is true for a von Neumann algebra $A$:

> **Theorem:** Let $A$ be a von Neumann algebra. Then every self-adjoint element $h\in A$, i.e $h=h^*$, is the limit of a sequence of linear combinations of mutually orthogonal idempotent elements of $A$.

I am, however, looking for a textbook in which this result is mentioned and a proof is given.

Can anyone please help provide me with such a reference?

Comment: I don't know about a text where this is explicitly stated, but I do know of a book that contains all of the essential ingredients are proven.  Is this sufficient?

Comment: @Aweygan that would most definitely help, thank you very much! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The book *A Course in Functional Analysis* by John Conway (the analyst, not the group theorist) contains all the necessary ingredients in Chapter IX.

Suppose the von Neumann algebra acts on the Hilbert space $H$, and $h\in A$ is self-adjoint.  Using theorems IX$.2.2$ (the spectral theorem) and theorem IX$.1.10$, $h$ is the limit of a sequence of linear combinations of orthogonal projections in $\mathcal B(H)$ (the projections come from the spectral measure associated with $h$ on disjoint subsets of $\sigma(h)$). By Theorem IX$.2.2(c)$ and Fuglede's theorem (a specific case of Theorem IX$.6.7$), all of these projections are in $A''$, and therefore in $A$.